# Which crimp tool to use with SSH-003GA-P0.2?

Tags: crimp

I'm planning to crimp SSH-003GA-P0.2 crimp terminals to go into JSTSHDR-20V-S-B connectors.

How do I figure out which is the proper crimp tool I have to use to succeed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the datasheet.

Comment: A similar question has been here before years ago.  The answer is similar.  Use the vendor recommended tool or a near as possible alternative based on crimped terminal dimensions.  I was offered a simple over centre parallel jaw action hand tool by a JST agent in South Africa when I purchased ten thousand contacts and it cost more than the contacts.  It is fiddly work to get good crimps but possible with care I only needed a few hundred contacts all told but there were no easy alternatives.  Pre-crimped is a good idea when available, if ordered from a harness supplier it may save you time..

Comment: @KalleMP thanks for your comment. Perhaps you could link me please the tool you've got from them? Thanks

Comment: My experience with this problem was 20 years ago so you will have to locate your own JST supplier and ask them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you go to the Digikey page of the [SSH-003GA-P0.2](https://www.digikey.nl/product-detail/nl/jst-sales-america-inc/SSH-003GA-P0.2/455-1435-1-ND/760078), you can scroll down and see the Tool section.
This specifies the [YRS-859](https://www.digikey.nl/product-detail/nl/jst-sales-america-inc/YRS-859/455-2569-ND/2298138) as compatible hand tool.

That is super easy. When there is no tool section, you can look for "other customers also bought", or "relevant products" that you often find at the bottom of any online store. There will at lease be some hints in here to brand or off-brand tools.

It also specifies the tools per part in the table available from JST.
http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eTOOL-5A.pdf
Which for JST is obvious, but some lesser known brands might not be clear about this.

Comment: +1. Something about men, feeding, teaching and fishing :)

Comment: @Shamtam They'll come round they see the price of the tool.

Comment: @Jeroen3 thanks for the answer. The price indeed is pretty unreasonable. Are there any good ways of looking up for some alternatives? Besides the digikey 'another people also bought'/'relevant products' sections? Thanks

Comment: @user59271 Yes, buy them with wire already crimped on.

Comment: I've used a variant of that tool. It's so expensive because it is a production grade tool. It takes in a roll of pins and cuts the pin off the roll with every shrimp. It does not auto-forward which would have been nice, but it has detents that allow easy pin alignment. The tool is rated for tens of thousands of operations. The cheaper tool loads pins one at a time by hand.

Comment: Off brand crimp tools exist and can be quite good. They "void your warranty" (i.e. not using the recommended tool means the manufacturer isn't liable for failed connections) when used, generally, but unless you're a massive company selling thousands or millions of devices (and thus can presumably afford the "official" crimp tool) you probably don't care. Quality may be lower, but the price is generally on the order of 5% or less that of the recommended tool, so for low-quantity and hobbyist uses it's probably the way to go.

Comment: @Hearth thank you very much for the comment. How do I find a suitable off brand crimp tool? Particularly for this crimp size, it appears to be one of the tiniest ones. Thanks

Comment: Here is some discussion about the same problem with some ideas.  https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10219